# How to integrate git-aware-prompt with shortened pathname in bash

Tags: git, bash, command-prompt

I am using a [git aware prompt](https://github.com/jimeh/git-aware-prompt)
and I would like to integrate it with a shortened version of the path name

The shortened pwd is created dynamically with

```
python ~/.short.pwd.py
```

And the git-aware-prompt commands are

```
export GITAWAREPROMPT=~/.bash/git-aware-prompt
source "${GITAWAREPROMPT}/main.sh"
export PS1="\${debian_chroot:+(\$debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w \[$txtcyn\]\$git_branch\[$txtred\]\$git_dirty\[$txtrst\]\$ "
```

I tried playing with some mixes of `$debian_chroot` or `\u@\h:\w` with `(python ~/.short.pwd.py)` with no luck, yet I am not a bash expert.

Anyone knows how to merge them, so I'd get both short path indication and git-aware-prompt?

Thanks!

Comment: `\w` is the current working directory in the prompt; don't you just want to replace that with `\$shortpwd`?

Comment: @chepner, that almost worked. It made me realize that I have to fix the question. It didn't work because I've had an error, I should not use a env. variable for shortpwd, but to create it dynamically. I edited the question now.

Comment: @chepner, your comment helped me solve my question. I will write an answer, unless you'd like to do it and get the credit. (Replacing \u@\h:\w with $(python ~/.short.pwd.py) )

Comment: Go ahead; you know what you did to fix your prompt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the question with @chepner assistance in comments, by replacing `\u@\h:\w` with `$(python ~/.short.pwd.py)`.

Finally the updated `export` is

```
export PS1="\${debian_chroot:+(\$debian_chroot)}\$(python ~/.short.pwd.py) \[$txtcyn\]\$git_branch\[$txtred\]\$git_dirty\[$txtrst\]\$ "
```